# Attempted to move a file with mv command and now it is lost?

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I was trying to move a file with `mv` to see it works and now I cannot find it.

The command I entered was:

```
sudo mv ~/Documents/Books/UTMAnalysis.pdf /Desktop
```

I am using OS X. Similar questions mentioned it might be in the root directory or somewhere as a hidden file.

In the root directory there is a Desktop, but is that not the existing folder?

Comment: Hi! Does directory `Previous`exist? What did you intend for the command to do?

Comment: Sorry the `Previous` was a typo. I intended to move the `UTMAnalysis.pdf` file from `~/Documents/Books` to the `~/Desktop`.

Comment: _Why_ did you use `sudo` if you just wanted to move a file from one that your user owns directory to another directory that your user owns? AFAIK there's no root privileges needed to do that...

Comment: Yes I don't think I'd need root privileges to do that. Originally I tried without `sudo` but was denied. However I suspect that is because I was not just moving a file to `~/Desktop/` but instead was renaming the file and moving it to the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect one of the following:

#### renamed

If /Desktop did not exist when you ran that command it would have renamed the file "UTMAnalysis.pdf" to be "Dektop". You could confirm if it was a directory or a file with this command:

`ls -ld /Desktop`

If it's a directory the first character will be a "d" whereas if it's a file it will be a "-".

```
linux-okrz:~ # ls -ld file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 29 19:43 file
linux-okrz:~ # ls -ld directory/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 29 19:45 directory/
```

You can also run the `stat` command on it to see information on them:

```
linux-okrz:~ # stat file
  File: 'file'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 20709419    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-04-29 19:43:57.620769552 -0600
Modify: 2017-04-29 19:43:57.620769552 -0600
Change: 2017-04-29 19:43:57.620769552 -0600
 Birth: -
linux-okrz:~ # stat directory
  File: 'directory'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 20709424    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-04-29 19:45:52.036413879 -0600
Modify: 2017-04-29 19:45:52.036413879 -0600
Change: 2017-04-29 19:45:52.036413879 -0600
 Birth: -
```

On the right-hand side of the output you can see "regular file" vs "directory". If it's a file then you can rename it back and check to make sure you can still access it.

#### Inside /Desktop

The next possibility is that it is in the `/Desktop` directory. If it is a directory(should be confirmed from previous suggestion), you didn't indicate whether you've checked in there or not. You can run this command as root to get a full layout of the directories and files in that directory:

`ls -lah /Desktop/`

From there you can see if you find the UTMAnalysis.pdf file.

#### Hidden Action

The third possibility is that there is another command or action that's been taken before or after this command you've listed that's done something else to the file. You can check your history with the `history` command to see if you can find any other command that has acted on that file. You could also try searching for the file with a find command as root:

`find / -type f -name "*UTMAnalysis.pdf*"`

If the above command doesn't find it then it either doesn't have "UTMAnalysis.pdf" in its name anymore, or no longer exists on the system.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive response! It seems I renamed the original file. 


However that confuses me a bit because I do have a directory named `Desktop`, if I had wanted to move a file there should I have written `sudo mv ~/Documents/Books/UTMAnalysis.pdf /Desktop/` instead? Is the trailing `/` necessary? Or is it the lack of a `~`?

Comment: @al-exander No problem! So the problem is that the directory you are wanting to put it in isn't `/Desktop` but rather `~/Desktop`. The initial `/` means that it is the root of the filesystem whereas `~` is short-hand for your user's home directory(`/home/<username>`). The Desktop directory you are seeing is the one inside of your user's home directory. So if the file was owned by your user you could run the command like this: `mv ~/Documents/Books/UTMAnalysis.pdf ~/Desktop/` If the file was owned by root you'd have to add `sudo` to the beginning of that command. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`mv` assumed that because the target was not an existing directory that you wanted to move `UTMAnalysis.pdf` to the root directory and have it named `Desktop`.

To correct this error, use `sudo mv /Desktop ~/Desktop/UTMAnalysis.pdf`

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is what happened. As I mentioned in the reply to TopHat, this leads to another question. I do have a directory named `Desktop`, if I had wanted to move a file there should I have written `sudo mv ~/Documents/Books/UTMAnalysis.pdf /Desktop/` instead? Is the trailing `/` necessary? Or is it the lack of a `~`?

Comment: the trailing `/` is not required, but is good practice (and is inserted when you autocomplete a path with the tab key) as it ensures that you are targeting a directory.  With a trailing `/` on a target that is not a directory, the command will fail with `mv: failed to access '[target]': Not a directory`

Comment: I see! So with a `/` at the end I would avoid (some) future mistakes, good to know!